"To touch somebody’s ears"?
Ruth Rendell, Adam, Eve and Pinch Me, 2001, p. 274:

A solicitor came to live next door to my parents when I was a kid. I’ve always remembered my father saying to my mother, he’s a lawyer, don’t touch his ears.

The meaning is quite clear; what I’d like to know, is to touch somebody’s ears an established idiom or a writer’s idiolect?

"The meaning is quite clear; " -- Could you tell us what the meaning is?

«it's better not to irritate a lawyer», I’d say.

No, it is  it not an established  idiom.

I took it as: touching a lawyer's ear, an intimate body part, will result in a lawsuit.

Thanks a lot Gio and XCX!

@XCX Seems very weird to name that specific body part, it's not especially intimate IMHO; I think they'd just say "Don't touch him".

You would say that to a kid, especially in the UK, where people got or used to get their ears "boxed". Ears are quite sensitive. It is not an idiom. It's an idea.

@Lambie That's hitting them on the side of the head (the temples are near the ears), not specifically the ears. And this would be like telling someone not to shake hands with someone because teachers used to rap kids on the knuckles as a punishment.

@Barmar The expression is to box someone's ears. The men used to hit boys on the ears while making a fist.

@Lambie M-W: "to hit someone on the sides of the head or on the ears". But the real point is that it's hitting, not just touching. It's like the difference between a punch and a fist-bump.

@Barmar We may be overreaching here.

This is possibly a reference to the film There's Something About Mary, which contains the character Warren Jensen, who Wikipedia describes as

Warren Jensen, Mary's intellectually disabled brother who is very protective of his ears.

The film came out in 1998, only three years before Adam, Eve, and Pinch Me.

The narrator is describing his childhood, so that presumably predates the movie.

Before There's something about Mary, I don't think there was anything in popular culture about touching people's ears.

I agree, perhaps it's more of a niche reference relating to training animals like horses or dogs.

This seems to be coincidental - being protective about his ears seems to be an idiosyncratic and irrational fear: it is probably part of his disability.

@Greybeard: If there is one intellectually disabled person who is very protective of his ears, Ruth Rendell may have extrapolated the existence of other such people in the past, and thus used this expression. Anybody who has seen There's Something About Mary, which was a large percentage of people in 2001, would understand the reference. You don't have to assume that Ruth Rendell is claiming that the father has seen the movie.

@PeterShor. From the passage, I get the distinct impression that there is some mythical and malevolent creature that objects to having its ears touched and, to which, the father eludes. The speaker and family are obviously happy with it, but it appears nobody here is.

@Greybeard: Why a creature and not a person?, which I think is more likely.

The reference to the ears is limited to those two lines; speaking them is a solicitor, a very secondary character who doesn‘t appear anywhere else in the novel, so, as far as conjectures, anything goes… I am satisfied with knowing it’s not an idiom. Thanks a lot you all.
